# issue in save View State and Load View State

Tags: c#, state-management

Created the Custom Server Control

Trying to store the properties in view state but on post backs i am not able to get values which are stored in the state previously .
 following is the code

```
  private int attachmentId;
    public int AttachmentId
    {
        get { return attachmentId; }
        set { attachmentId = value; }
    }

  private string attachmentName = string.Empty;
    public string  AttachmentName
    {
        get { return attachmentName; }
        set { attachmentName = value; }
    }


 protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        object[] state = (object[])savedState;
        base.LoadViewState(state[0]);
        this.attachmentName = (string)state[1];
        this.attachmentId = (int)state[2];           
    }

 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
        this.AttachmentName ="HelloText.txt";
        this.AttachmentID = 10;
         }
    }

 protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        object[] state = new object[3];
        state[0] = base.SaveViewState();
        state[1] = this.attachmentName;
        state[2] = this.attachmentId;

        return state;
    }
```

on first page load values get added in the View state 
if any post back will happen values should be available which is not happening now can any on help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should consider below options for achieving this.It is more neat and clean way to achieve.

**Example of Class/Enum**

```
public Color XXX
{
    get { return (Color)ViewState["XXX"]; }
    set { ViewState["XXX"] = value; }
}
```

**Example of Boolean**

```
public bool AskForUpdate
{
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["AskForUpdate"] == null)
                return false;
            else
                return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["AskForUpdate"]);
        }
        set { ViewState["AskForUpdate"] = value; }
}
```

**Example of Integer**

```
 public int RevisionID
    {
        get
        {
            int revisionID = 0;
            int.TryParse(hdnRevisionID.Value, out revisionID);
            if (revisionID == 0)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["ProposalID"] != null)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ProposalID"].ToString(), out revisionID))
                    {
                        hdnRevisionID.Value = revisionID.ToString();
                        return revisionID;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return revisionID;
            }
            return revisionID;
        }
    }
```

**Example of String**

```
 public string userGroup
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["userGroup"] == null)
                return "";
            return (ViewState["userGroup"].ToString());
        }
        set { ViewState["userGroup"] = value; }
    }
```

On your existing implementation should also work.You are not calling base method in LoadViewState.

```
  base.LoadViewState(savedState);
```

Comment: Still facing same issue. it is working in a simple page but if creating the custom control it is giving issue.

Comment: Have you still kept LoadViewState,SaveViewState these methods?

Comment: No. but what is the issue with the approach what i am using ?? it should also work.

Comment: My code works also in a user control/custom control.Just check thoroughly if something else is sensing problem.

Comment: Ok see my edit. in your LoadViewState() why not adding base.LoadViewState(savedState);

Comment: See carefully you should do `base.LoadViewState(savedState)`;and also this should come before  `object[] state = (object[])savedState`;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91282/discussion-between-navoneel-and-liquid).